# Showing pictures and descriptions stored in Firestore in an Android CardView

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I´ve been searching trough the internet to find an example which shows the basic  implementation of images and descriptions from Firestore in a CardView in Android but i just found examples where pictures were added to Firebase Storage via an Upload Button. I just want to add pictures and infos through the Firebase console; not with my app.

For my current project i want to implement a picture and a small description to a CardView. My Firestore database looks like this:

[image]

The pictures are actually stored in Firebase Storage but i thought it would be easier to implement all this into a CardView if it is all in one database.

It would be nice to have an amateur-friendly example to start off. I have knowledge about the Firebase integration in Android Studio. The Firestore library is integrated but do i need another one (maybe the Storage library) besides that?

These are my doings so far:

card_item.xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
app:cardBackgroundColor="#FBEFFB">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/picture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxHeight="50dp" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/picture"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:text="Text" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

The RelativeLayout is in a CardView but it doesnt get inserted here.

fragment_home.xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".HomeFragment">
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:id="@+id/tomap"/>
```

HomeFragment.java

```
public class HomeFragment extends AppCompatActivity {



private Button tomap;
private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
private CollectionReference PicturesRef = db.collection("Pictures");

private NoteAdapter adapter;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_home);

    tomap = findViewById(R.id.tomap);

    tomap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           openMapsActivity();
        }
    });

    setUpRecyclerView();

}

public void openMapsActivity () {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class );
     startActivity(intent);
}

private void setUpRecyclerView() {
    Query query = PicturesRef.orderBy("Name", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);

    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Note> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Note>()
            .setQuery(query, Note.class)
            .build();

    adapter = new NoteAdapter(options);

    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    adapter.startListening();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    adapter.stopListening();
}
```

}

Note.java

```
public class Note {
private String Name;
private String Info;


public Note() {
    //empty constructor needed
}

public Note(String title, String description) {
    this.Name = title;
    this.Info = description;
}

public String getName() {
    return Name;
}

public String getInfo() {
    return Info;
}
```

}

NoteAdapter.java

```
public class NoteAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Note, NoteAdapter.NoteHolder> {

/**
 * Create a new RecyclerView adapter that listens to a Firestore Query.  See
 * {@link FirestoreRecyclerOptions} for configuration options.
 *
 * @param options
 */
public NoteAdapter(FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Note> options) {
    super(options);
}

@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(NoteHolder holder, int position, Note model) {

    holder.textViewTitle.setText(model.getName());
    holder.textViewDescription.setText(model.getInfo());


}

@NonNull
@Override
public NoteHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_item,
            parent, false);
    return new NoteHolder(v);
}

class NoteHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView textViewTitle;
    TextView textViewDescription;


    public NoteHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textViewTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        textViewDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: @AlexMamo I worked with an example that created the exact thing i want to achieve but i wasn´t able to integrate pictures with that path link in that way. So i managed to integrate TextViews in my CardView but no ImageView. I think i cant put the right syntax into the Adapter file in Android Studio. I am not really a pro in coding.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Dee Jott if you haven't solved the problem yet test this out and see if it would work.

**If you want to display picture on your cardview you should first of all add extra code in your Note.java file**

```
public class Note {
    private String Name;
    private String Info;
    private String Picture;


    public Note() {
        //empty constructor needed
    }

    public Note(String title, String description, String picture) {
        this.Name = title;
        this.Info = description;
        this.Picture = picture;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public String getInfo() {
        return Info;
    }

    // Getters and setters to get the picture from firestore

    public String getPicture() {
        return Picture;
    }

    public void setPicture(String picture) {
        this.Picture = picture;
    }
}
```

**After you have changed your Note.java file go to your gradle and implement this.**

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
```

**When you have implemented picasso in your gradle go back to your NoteAdapter and add these lines**

```
public class NoteAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Note, NoteAdapter.NoteHolder> {

    /**
     * Create a new RecyclerView adapter that listens to a Firestore Query.  See
     * {@link FirestoreRecyclerOptions} for configuration options.
     *
     * @param options
     */
    public NoteAdapter(FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Note> options) {
        super(options);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(NoteHolder holder, int position, Note model) {

        holder.textViewTitle.setText(model.getName());
        holder.textViewDescription.setText(model.getInfo());
        holder.setPicture(model.getPicture());


    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public NoteHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_item,
                parent, false);
        return new NoteHolder(v);
    }

    class NoteHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView textViewTitle;
        TextView textViewDescription;
        ImageView imageViewPicture;


        public NoteHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textViewTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            textViewDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);
        }

        public void setPicture(String picture) {
            imageViewPicture = itemView.findViewById(R.id.picture);
            Picasso.get().load(picture).into(imageViewPicture);
        }
    }

}
```

**And last add these lines to your HomeFragment**

```
public class HomeFragment extends AppCompatActivity {


    private Button tomap;
    private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    private CollectionReference PicturesRef = db.collection("Pictures");

    private NoteAdapter adapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_home);

        tomap = findViewById(R.id.tomap);

        tomap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openMapsActivity();
            }
        });

        setUpRecyclerView();

    }

    public void openMapsActivity() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void setUpRecyclerView() {
        Query query = PicturesRef;

        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Note> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Note>()
                .setQuery(query, Note.class)
                .build();

        adapter = new NoteAdapter(options);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }
}
```

**I Hope this works.**

Comment: The code looks good. But in my Note.java file it says 'setPicture' is never used. Also, as soon as i type in the correct collection name "Pictures" into my HomeFragment.java file, the app just closes itself after i tried to run the app.

Comment: UPDATE: Right now entering the name of my collection is working but there is still no cardview to see in my HomeFragment. I also removed the setter function in the Note. java file although i believe that this part is important. Any furhter help you can give me?

Comment: Is "imageViewPicture" correctly addressed in the NoteAdapter file? 

holder.textViewTitle.setText(model.getName());
        holder.textViewDescription.setText(model.getInfo());
        holder.???.setPicture(model.getPicture());